# Writing tag wikis for broad/general tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

How should we write tag wikis for broad or general tags? Such as `algorithm`, or `history`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Tag excerpts are not meant to simply define what the *word* of a tag means. They are meant to describe when and how those tags should be used on this site specifically.

Since this site is not generically about either *algorithms* OR *history*, it becomes especially important to describe how those subjects fit in the context of *this* site.

I see some potentially misleading tags like [python], [engine], and [storage]. Adding a bit of context about where they should be used can help avoid the occasional off-topic question that may not fit this site at all.